# Unreserved Identifiers in Java Script

Tags: javascript

JavaScript has about 44 identifiers which are reserved keywords but Infinity, NaN and undefined are categorized as unreserved identifiers in JavaScript. Why are they called identifiers and why are they not reserved ?

Comment: Classically, this is a mistake that is rather impossible to fix now. They should have been reserved (like `null` is for example). This is why you see some people use `void 0` instead of `undefined`. It's also why you can do quirky stuff like `Infinity++`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`undefined`,`NaN` and `Infinity` are actually **properties** of the global object:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN

> NaN is a property of the global object.
>
> The initial value of NaN is Not-A-Number — the same as the value of Number.NaN. In modern browsers, NaN is a non-configurable, non-writable property. Even when this is not the case, avoid overriding it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined

> undefined is a property of the global object, i.e. it is a variable in global scope.
>
> The initial value of undefined is the primitive value undefined.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/infinity

> Infinity is a property of the global object, i.e. it is a variable in global scope.
>
> The initial value of Infinity is Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY. The value Infinity (positive infinity) is greater than any other number including itself. This value behaves mathematically like infinity; for example, any positive number multiplied by Infinity is Infinity, and anything divided by Infinity is 0.

---

Refer to [ELS5 Section 15.1.1](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_15.1.1)

> **15.1.1.1   NaN**
>
> The value of NaN is NaN (see 8.5). This property has the attributes { [[Writable]]: false, [[Enumerable]]: false, [[Configurable]]: false }.
>
> **15.1.1.2   Infinity**
>
> The value of Infinity is +∞ (see 8.5). This property has the attributes { [[Writable]]: false, [[Enumerable]]: false, [[Configurable]]: false }.
>
> **15.1.1.3   undefined**
>
> The value of undefined is undefined (see 8.1). This property has the attributes { [[Writable]]: false, [[Enumerable]]: false, [[Configurable]]: false }.

You might notice the [[Writable]]: false. In newer browsers, assigning a new value to undefined has no effect:

```
> undefined = 'foo'
< "foo"
> undefined
< undefined
```

Comment: worth to mention that modern browser won't allow you to override undefined ( etc...). not to mention strict mode.

Comment: @RoyiNamir sure they will `(function(undefined){ console.log(undefined);})("Cat");` All they'll do is stop you from overriding the global object's undefined property.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Sure. that's what I meant.  ( should have clarified that it won't allow to override GLOBAL object  ( as opposed to parameter named the same))