# Infinity, NaN and undefined: an unreserved keyword?

Tags: javascript, syntax

The MDN documentation states:

```
Reserved words actually only apply to Identifiers (vs. IdentifierNames) . As described in es5.github.com/#A.1, these are all IdentifierNames which do not exclude ReservedWords
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords

The list of reserved keywords, however, does not include the identifiers `Infinity`, `NaN` and `undefined`.

These do appear to act as if they are a keyword. Why are they called identifiers and not reserved keywords?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unreserved Identifiers in Java Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23979431/unreserved-identifiers-in-java-script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`undefined`,`NaN` and `Infinity` are actually *properties* of the global object.

See my full answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23979431/unreserved-identifiers-in-java-script/23979505#23979505)

Comment: Why does the documentation refer to these properties as "identifier"? Why were they not added to the language as a "reserved keyword"?

Comment: This is a design choice. I cannot find any discussion as to why, but the specification [here](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.1) (Section 15.1.1) explains the design more formally.

Answer (score 0):

They are all properties of the global object, but they aren't reserved; you're syntactically free to declare variables with those names (as long as you're not on the top level - on the top level, the identifiers refer to the values on the global object, and cannot be reassigned):

```js
console.log(
  window.hasOwnProperty('undefined'),
  window.hasOwnProperty('NaN'),
  window.hasOwnProperty('Infinity'),
);
(() => {
  const undefined = 'foo';
  const NaN = 'bar';
  const Infinity = 'baz';
  console.log('No error');
})();
```

Reserved keywords, on the other hand, cannot be used as identifiers (variable names).

Comment: The code runs fine in strict mode too. If the declarations were on the top level instead, they would throw in both strict and sloppy mode.